# Posição de DIV em relação a outra com conteúdo dinâmico

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, div

Tenho duas `divs` na minha página, uma `class="rodape"` e outra `class="content"`.

A primeira é o rodapé da página, e ajusta sua posição em relação ao `bottom` dos conteúdos fixos da página sem problemas.

Porém, a segunda `div` carrega conteúdo dinâmico (através de uma verificação em `Javascript`, exibida ao final da pergunta). Se o conteúdo for de altura igual ou menor que o conteúdo fixo, sem problemas. Mas, se for maior, a `div` ropadé não se move de acordo.

[image: Como fica em conteúdos extensos...]

Segue trecho do `css` para cada elemento:

```
.rodape{
    background-color:#013852;
    height:380px;
    width:100%;
    margin-top: 30px;
    position:absolute;
}
.content{
    display:none;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 5%;
    width:35%;
    margin-top: 2px;
    padding-left: 5%;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    border-left:#CCC solid 1px;
}
```

A `div content` é inicialmente `display: none`, pois depende da ação da finalização do vídeo ao lado (lado esquerdo da tela tem um player) para ser exibida:

```
<script>
    var myVideo = document.getElementById("myVideo"); 
    function endFunction() {
        myVideo.width = 495;
        myVideo.height = 324;
        document.getElementById('content').style.display = "inline-block";
    }
    function playFunction() {
        myVideo.width = 720;
        myVideo.height = 445;
        document.getElementById('content').style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
```

E a tabela que é exibida não é exatamente dinâmica (está inserida no `HTML` inicialmente), mas sua exibição depende de uma consulta `PHP`, mais ou menos assim:

```
<?php
    switch($r['tipo_resposta']){
        case '1': //exibe a tabela
        break;

        case '2': //exibe um input text
        break;

        default:
    }
?>
```

Comment: por que você está usando o position absolute no rodapé?

Comment: @haykou havia colocado absolute para outras páginas. Nesse caso específico, tentei alterar para position relative, mas não fez diferença, o problema persistiu...

Comment: se você puder colocar o html e o css no exemplo ficaria mais fácil, tirando o position absolute, e colocando um display inline block, com altura e largura a div .content iria aumentar o tamanho conforme o conteúdo.

Comment: Vou acrescentar algumas outras informações na pergunta... Vi aqui que tem mais coisas que certamente estão influenciando o comportamento...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenta mudar o `.rodape` para:

```
.rodape {
   background-color: #013852;
   height: 380px;
   width: 100%;
   margin-top: 30px;
   position: static;
   bottom: 0;
}
```

#### Editado

Não tinha me atendado ao `.content` estar como `float`, faz o seguinte, bota uma `div` qualquer entre a `div` de conteúdo e a `div` de rodapé, onde nessa `div` é aplicado o estilo:

```
.clear { 
    clear: both
}
```

Teoricamente, com essa alteração, sua `div` de rodapé sempre ficará imediatamente abaixo da `div` de conteúdo, tendo que fazer algo diferente se você quiser que ela sempre esteja no fim da página.

Comment: Com essa alteração, o conteúdo da DIV content passou para frente da DIV rodape, mas a posição permaneceu a mesma...

Comment: @Atoyansk Editei o post com algumas informações que podem te ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

Creio que se você utilizasse o [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) seria melhor nesse caso, ficaria algo do tipo:

**HTML**

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="content">content</div>
    <div class="rodape">rodape</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
*{margin:0;padding:0;} /*reset básico*/
.main{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    width:100%;
    height:100%; /*ou o tanto que você quiser*/
}
.content, .rodape{
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
    background:red;
}
.content{
    flex-grow:1;
    background:green;
}
```